# User email verification link

Tags: users, emails

Is there a way to store/save the user verification email link in the database after a new user creates an account?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) enables you to alter any email messages sent out from [`hook_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail/7) if you know the specific key associated with the email. In this case, the key is `user_register_no_approval_required`. From that point, all you have to do is parse the email message body for the relevant URL and save it to your desired location.

```
function MYMODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if($message['id'] == 'user_register_no_approval_required') {
    //@TODO: Parse $message['body'] for email verification link and save it
  }
}
```